# Double quotes in csv-table cell

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am struggling to add a cell with double quotes in the `csv-table`.

```
.. csv-table:: 
   :header: f,d

   2,"ts*"
```

the above one works fine.
But if I try to get the cell  as `ts"*"` instead of `ts*`, it starts throwing an error :

> Error with CSV data in "csv-table" directive: ',' expected after '"'

I tried using escape characters (like `\` ) but it didn't work.

I was trying it here : [online editor](http://rst.ninjs.org/#Li4gY3N2LXRhYmxlOjogCiAgIDpoZWFkZXI6IGYsZAoKICAgMiwidHMqIgoKCgouLiBjc3YtdGFibGU6OiAKICAgOmhlYWRlcjogZixkCgogICAyLCJ0c1wiKlwiIg==)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think i found the solution; There is an option to specify the escape sequence `:escape: '`.

```
.. csv-table:: 
   :escape: '
   :header: f,d

   2,"ts'"*'""
```

It is now showing the cell as `ts"*"`.

Try it [online](http://rst.ninjs.org/#Li4gY3N2LXRhYmxlOjogCiAgIDpoZWFkZXI6IGYsZAoKICAgMiwidHMqIgoKCgouLiBjc3YtdGFibGU6OiAKICAgOmVzY2FwZTogJwogICA6aGVhZGVyOiBmLGQKCiAgIDIsInRzJyIqJyIi)